# NSRegularExpression to extract url between 2 strings

Tags: objective-c, regex, foundation, nsregularexpression

I'm using an `NSRegularExpression` to extract a URL between 2 strings, here is the whole string:

```
  <a href="/url?q=http://www.myurl.com/videos/how-to/&amp;sa=
```

I need to extract part between `/url?q=` and `&amp;sa=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be found and dug out using a regex with positive look-behind and look-ahead, like this:

```
NSString *orgStr = @"<a href=\"/url?q=http://www.myurl.com/videos/how-to/&amp;sa=";

NSString *URLRegExPattern = @"(?<=url\\?q=).*(?=&amp;sa=)";

NSError *regExErr;
NSRegularExpression *URLRegEx = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:URLRegExPattern 
                                                                          options:0
                                                                            error:&regExErr];

NSString *URLString = nil;

NSRange range = [URLRegEx rangeOfFirstMatchInString:orgStr 
                                            options:0 
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, orgStr.length)];

if (!NSEqualRanges(range, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
    URLString = [orgStr substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
}

NSLog(@"URL: %@", URLString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methode of `NSString` : `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator`